# Which is correct "If you are tired" or "If you tired"?

Tags: grammaticality, clauses

I went through some documents about the usage of if clause. But still confused
about the usage of clause sentence.

Which sentence is correct in the below two sentences?

> 1. If you are tired, get some sleep.
> 2. If you tired, get some sleep.

Answer (score 2):

"If you are tired, get some sleep."
Or "If you're tired, get some sleep."

"If you tired" is changing the adjective *tired* into a verb.
You could however say: "If you tired yourself to exhaustion, get some sleep".

Answer (score 0):

"If you are tired, get some sleep."  -  relates to future and means that when you get tired (because of activity you do now) you will go to bed.

"If you tired (eg. after some running), **you would** get some sleep" - "tired" is a verb here and relates to your state now. Second sentence is a possible action that you would do when first is true. Read it as below:

"If you tired out (but you don't), **you would** get some sleep."